# spring validator without using properties file for show error messages

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-validator

I want configuration for show error messages on jsp using spring validator,but without using this configuration for message.properties.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>message</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**error.rejectValue(String field,
                 String errorCode,
                 Object[] errorArgs,
                 String defaultMessage)**

Register a field error for the specified field of the current object (respecting the current nested path, if any), using the given error description.

The field name may be null or empty String to indicate the current object itself rather than a field of it. This may result in a corresponding field error within the nested object graph or a global error if the current object is the top object.

**Parameters:**

**field** - the field name (may be null or empty String)

**errorCode** - error code, interpretable as a message key

**errorArgs** - error arguments, for argument binding via MessageFormat (can be null)

**defaultMessage** - fallback default message

[reference link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

Use

**error.rejectvalue** with three parameters("**name of path variable**" , "**any name**" , "***message you want to show***");

just like

```
error.rejectvalue("Name", "msg.name", "please enter name");
```